# JBDC/Spark/SQL: Unable to write data to SQL from Spark (invalid Base-64 string)

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am unable to write data to my SQL server from Databricks using PySpark. No matter the data (even the trivial example below), I get this error:

`SQLServerException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters`

Here is what I do:

```
# create df
df = spark.createDataFrame([('A', 5, 0),('A',6, 0),('B',3, 0)], ['id', 'value', 'currentVersion'])

# write
df.write \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=<db>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30") \
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true") \
  .option("enableServicePrincipalAuth", "true") \
  .option("truncate", "true") \
  .option("dbTable", "dbo.test") \
  .option("tempDir", "abfss://<fsname>@<storagename>.dfs.core.windows.net/temp") \
  .save()
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be with the way secrets were passed:

For example, secrets should be passed like this:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.sqldw.jdbc.service.principal.client.id", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="scopename", key="keyvault_key"))
```

Rather than:

```
# this will fail
authenticationKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope="scopename", key="keyvault_key")

spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.sqldw.jdbc.service.principal.client.id", authenticationKey)
```